# Xcode Constraints issues

Tags: xcode, user-interface, autolayout, constraints

I am working on an App and I want the UI to look the same in every device screen. I have an iPhone 6 device and use iPhone 5 in the simulator; when I run the App, it looks Ok in my iPhone 6, but it looks like the following in the iPhone 5 simulator...

[image]

I added some constraints but I have been having trouble with these buttons and the labels. How can I fix this? I thank you in advance for your answers.

**UPDATE**
I erased all constraints and started over, now the final screen looks like the following...

[image]

Looks better now, the only thing I could not fix was the position of the  two buttons (Agregar and Salir) because they are located in the centre and now they moved a bit to the right.

Here are my constraints

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constraint in Xcode UI is respectively, so you need to set all of the constraint for each element, not only for those button. Every single element is constraint to each other, so make sure that each element has already set its constraint to another element.

Comment: Hello, I've updated my question. The screen looks better now, but the 2 last buttons are moved a bit to the left, how can I fix this?

Comment: Have you already add "Align Center X to: Superview" for those 2 last buttons?

Comment: Where can I find this option? For now I added a Center Horizontally in container for both buttons

Comment: Click on the button then on the right bottom, click: Add new Alignment Constraint -> Vertically in Container

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you only have constraints on those two items, try adding a constraint between the labels and the bottom buttons, so that there is always a space between those buttons.

Comment: It looks better now, but only the last two buttons are a bit moved to the right. I updated my question